# How to prevent HtmlGenericControl from encoding?

Tags: asp.net, servercontrols

I'm adding a script reference to a page header using a HtmlGenericControl.  The problem is that it encodes the src parameters.  So "&mkt=fr-FR" turns out as "&amp;mkt=fr-FR" and doesn't get the correct script.

```
  var scriptTag = new HtmlGenericControl("script");
  scriptTag.Attributes.Add("type", "text/javascript");
  scriptTag.Attributes.Add("src", scriptUrl);
```

Update

Here is the url

http://ecn.dev.virtualearth.net/mapcontrol/mapcontrol.ashx?v=6.2&mkt=fr-FR

Comment: That is the correct behavior. Attribute values should be html encoded. (Otherwise you would have an invalid html entity &mkt without ending semicolon.) What do you mean with "doesn't get the correct script"?

Comment: @SimonSvensson So the "&amp;mkt=fr-FR" isn't accepted as a valid parameter and the correct version of the script is not accessed.  It needs a "&mkt=fr-FR"

Comment: The &amp; is sent to your webbrowser, which parses html. The parsed string should end up being a single ampersand, just like &quot; should be parsed as a quotation mark. Have you checked what url is accessed (using something like Firebug of Fiddler)?

Comment: @SimonSvensson  Maybe I'm doing something wrong. I updated the question with the url.  If I type that url into the address bar with the correct &mkt=fr-FR vs &amp;mkt=fr-FR I get two different scripts.  I appreciate the help.

Comment: @SimonSvensson I figured it out, I was because some cultures, the one I was testing didn't have changes that were visible.  thanks for the help

Comment: @NullReference Please add your answer in case you solved it yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**[Did you try Literal Control - Mode Property ?](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.literal.mode.aspx)**

```
<asp:Literal ID="Literal1" Mode="Encode" Text="<script type='text/javascript' 
     language='javascript' src='Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min.js'></script>"
     runat="server">
</asp:Literal>
```

**Output**

```
<script type='text/javascript' language='javascript' 
                                      src='Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min.js'></script>
```